# Google Oauth2 in Erlang

Tags: oauth-2.0, erlang

How can I generate Google oauth2 Access token in Erlang.

I can generate the token in NodejS i. I need it in Erlang as all my rest api code is in Erlang.

Blockquote

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var MESSAGING_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
var SCOPES = [MESSAGING_SCOPE];

 var http = require('http')


 function getAccessToken(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var key = require("./ServiceAccountKey.json");
        var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
            key.client_email,
            null,
            key.private_key,
            SCOPES,
            null
        );
        jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
                return; 
            }
            resolve(tokens.access_token+" :  "+tokens.expiry_date);
        });
    });
}

 var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

     getAccessToken().then(function(access_token){

         res.end(access_token);

     });

 });

 server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started");
});
```

Tried to generate the Code

```
 URL="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
 Scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging",

 GetURL=URL++"?client_id="++ClientId++"&redirect_uri=com.example.app:/oauth2redirect&scope="++Scope++"&response_type=code",

        Response = httpc:request(URL),
        Response.
```

Return bad Request

Comment: Try to check value of `ClientId`, may be it is a `atom`, not is a `String`, so that you can't append like that. Otherwise, you can `io:format` the GetURL to see this is right URL or not. It seems that it should be `httpc:request(GetURL)` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're creating a URL with all required query parameters and putting it in the variable `GetURL`, but then you pass `URL`, which is just the base URL, to `httpc:request`.  Try passing `GetURL` instead, and see if that gets you further:

```
    Response = httpc:request(GetURL),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It was a typo . However in the main code it was GetURL

Comment: and return truple is``` {ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",400,"Bad Request"},
     [{"cache-control",
       "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"},
      {"date","Thu, 25 Apr 2019 01:25:13 GMT"},
      {"pragma","no-cache"},
      {"accept-ranges","none"},
      {"server","ESF"},
      {"vary","Accept-Encoding"},
      {"content-length","3255"},
      {"content-type","text/html; charset=utf-8"},
      {"expires","Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"},
      {"x-xss-protection","0"},
      {"x-frame-options","SAMEORIGIN"},
      {"alt-svc"...]}}```